# Archivo Context vacío después de actualizar . EF 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Acabo de agregar una nueva tabla en mi BD pero al querer actualizar mi archivo `.edmx` para obtener la entidad de mi nueva tabla mi `Context.cs` se queda vacío generando errores en cantidad.

1. ¿Por qué sucede esto?
2. ¿Existe otra manera de actualizar y agregar una tabla en mi entidad y que no me elimine las clases del `Context.cs`?

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Recompilaste tu proyecto nuevamente? es uno de los principales detalles de EF

Comment: Si lo limpié y recompile de nuevo este problema persiste...

Comment: No hay muchas opciones que ver fuera de ahí, debería ser transparente, a menos que verifiques si la tabla se agregó a la base correcta. o Comenta cual es el error que te arroja.

Comment: ¿Cuál Context.cs estás editando? Si es el autogenerado, siempre va a ser sobreescrito...